# How to use the Nacl module compiled by linux Toolchain in Html

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I run the "make TOOLCHAIN=linux" for the messaging example located under examples/api directory.other toolchains like pnacl,newlib,glibc are working properly.for linux toolchain it generates .so file,nmf is not automatically generated,so i created using CREATE_NMF command.when i change the HTML for linux toolchain like

```
    <body data-name='messaging' data-tools='linux' data-configs='Release' data-path='{tc}/{config}>
```

error like "This plugin is not supported".i dont know whether it is possible in this way.whether we can access .so like nexe/pexe.i only supposed to use linux toolchain because i am using "alsa/asoundlib.h" which is available only in linux and chrome os platform.finaly anyone tell how to access that .so file in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the messaging sample with the linux (native) toolchain by invoking:
TOOLCHAIN=linux make run

Please note, native toolchain support is only provided as a debugging aid. Shipping applications need to be built with a nacl or pnacl toolchain. When you run as described above, the browser is launched with command-line options to allow your .so to be loaded as a trusted ppapi plugin.

Comment: As you said shipping application built with nacl or pnacl but only linux toolchain accept the alsa/asoundlib.h while newlib,glibc,pnacl didnt accept that header.The question is how to use the generated .so file from linux and use that in nacl or pnacl buit because i supposed to use that .so file for accessing alsa api's.

Comment: whether i can serve like "make TOOLCHAIN=linux serve" and access that via "https://localhost:5103" in browser.

Comment: as you said running "TOOLCHAIN=linux make run" working in linux and this command serves the application but when check that in chromeos browser it shows error like "plugin not supported"

Comment: @BradleyNelson :`TOOLCHAIN=linux make run`launch the webserver, but it doesn't launch the web browser. So what is the required option to`allow your .so to be loaded as a trusted ppapi plugin`?